# Switch from Android Activity to MapActivity

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app, in which I have to move to MapActivity on Button click event.
But the app is crashing while switching from Activity to MapActivity.

can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code,

```
public class PopupActivity extends Activity implements GPSCallback
{
    .......
     public void display_map(String str)
     {
         Intent showMap_intent = new Intent(this,DisplayGoogleMaps.class);
         PopupActivity.this.startActivity(showMap_intent);
     }

}
```

This is my map Activity class

```
 public class DisplayGoogleMaps extends MapActivity 
{
    MapView mapView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
    }
}
```

And This is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".PopupActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:name=".DisplayGoogleMaps" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

there is nothing in error log while crashing!

Comment: Either paste your activity code or logs, so one can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Did you declare the map activity in your Manifest? Did you set the Android API package as Google APIs ?
These are mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "while switching from Activity to MapActivity"?
How do you switch? Any source code?

When you want to show some data in am MapView you have to start an Intent.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
    i.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
    i.putExtra("Value2", "This value two ActivityTwo");
    // Set the request code to any code you like, you can identify the
    // callback via this code
    startActivity(i);
}
```

From http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html => 6. Tutorial: Explicit intents and data transfer between activities

In your case the class >ActivityTwo< has to be the MapActivity